# Language development software for the children with autism

Tags: open-source, language

I have a 7 year-old child diagnosed with mild autism at age 3. My kid had almost no interest to speak until she was 66 months-old, nor she showed any sign that she understood a word. She has been open to the world outside of her, but not interested in spoken language.

She always loved music and singing. However, she would only imitate the music. She would use the vowels as notes, and imitate the intonation in the voice of the singer. These were the songs we hand-picked for her, since no uncontrolled screen time were allowed for her. As though singing was the only door to spoken language for her.

She started pronouncing whole words (including consonants) in songs at about 66 months-old. We started speech therapy. About a year later, she knows, speaks and shares the names of various objects, colors, numbers, letters with us. During this time, we started to use software on her tablet pc (uncontrolled screen time is still forbidden). We saw a great progress in her speech development. I got to learn that my kid has a talent and interest in the technological devices that the last two decades brought, just like any other millennial kid does.

She learns everything quickly from these software. She can match what she learns from her tablet with her environment, and she shares what she learns with us.

My **question** is: *Can you recommend open source multilingual software for the language development of the children with autism?* We live in Turkey, so we're trying to teach her Turkish.

Comment: Perhaps you could contact autism support organizations.  Also I wonder if you could adapt some existing software.